# Proxying websockets with single "proxyServer" to multiple targets

Tags: node.js, websocket, proxy, node-http-proxy

I am developing a nodeJS websocket proxy server. The use case is when a websocket request comes, I will check its credentials, add new headers and then based on its group (from user id) to redirect the websocket connection to its target webscoket server. 
I found most of the packages (such as node-http-proxy) supports single target. Is there a package supporting multiple targets ?

Answer (score 0):

From the README of node-http-proxy section, "Setup a stand-alone proxy server with custom server logic":

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  // You can define here your custom logic to handle the request
  // and then proxy the request.
  proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:5060' });
});
```

Therefore, you should be able to add your decision code in  the callback function and then make a `proxy.web()` call with your determined `target`.

Comment: It works. I ended with using:
server.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
  proxy.ws(req, socket, head, {target: 'ws://echo.websocket.org', changeOrigin: true, ws: true}, function(e) { console.log(e) });
 });
});

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help. What I did in that case

```
proxyServer.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
    const target = getTargetRoute(req)
    if (_.isNil(target)) {
      logger.error(`No target`)
      return
    }
    proxy.ws(req, socket, head, { target })
  })
```